# How to add/change progress value to the Progress Bar in Semantic UI (CSS) in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-css

I am Trying to add `Progress Bar` in React Application.

I am using Semantic CSS:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" />`

From Documentation (https://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html#/definition), I found following sample code but unable to add/change the progress

```
<div class="ui green progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
<div class="ui green progress" dataValue="1" dataTotal="100" id="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

But it is displaying as previous (no change).

**How to add/change progress `value`(it may increase/decrease in future) to the Progress Bar in ReactJS?**

*Adding a `value` is enough to continue*

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link you provided you are using standard [SemanticUI](https://semantic-ui.com/) (which is not updated since 2018).

In that case you need to follow the [usage page](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html#/usage) of the Progress Bar object to use it as Semantic UI wants. All the examples use jQuery, since it is a prerequisite of Semantic UI.

For example you can update `data-percent`

```html
<div class="ui progress" data-percent="74" id="example">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="label">74% Funded</div>
</div>
```

and then call

```js
$('#example').progress();
```

or you can directly update through JS with

```js
$('#example').progress({
  percent: 22
});
```

An other solution, since you are using React, is to move to [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/), that has a proper implementation of [Progress Bar](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/progress/) and overall best fits with React.

Comment: Can you please give me suggestion for this statement `$('#example').progress({
  percent: 22
});` to use in React and `data-percent` to use in React

Comment: @Mani `$('..')` is jQuery as SemanticUI is based on that. I'll improve the answer with this information.